# How to set default static page in Martini?

Tags: go, martini

I need to set default page "index.html" located in "public" folder. How I can do this in Martini framework?

I tryed this, but it doesn't work:

```
func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()
    static := martini.Static("public", martini.StaticOptions{Fallback: "/index.html", Exclude: "/send"})
    m.NotFound(static, http.NotFound)
    m.Use(static)
    m.Get("/send", sendEmail)
    m.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it correctly. Check if you really have an *index.html* in *public/* folder and it's accessible.

Currently, if the fallback file is inaccessible, error is silently discarded.

Comment: I cheked. Index,html is in public folder.
Screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/5r0_k_UTcv5WW

Comment: How do you run you app and what error do you get?

Here is my test of your code (index.html contains "Hello, World" in my case): http://imgur.com/2aI0TMO